# memory leak in objective-c xcode code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am getting an analyser error showing a potential leak in the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
mAngle = 0.0;
cligneBool = YES;

SoundManager *mSoundManager = [[SoundManager alloc] init];
[mSoundManager initOpenAL];
[mSoundManager loadSound:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bing.wav" ofType:nil] SoundKey:@"bing"];
[mSoundManager loadSound:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding.wav" ofType:nil] SoundKey:@"ding"];
[mSoundManager loadSound:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click.wav" ofType:nil] SoundKey:@"click"];
[mSoundManager loadSound:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"die.wav" ofType:nil] SoundKey:@"die"];
[mSoundManager loadSound:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kaboom.wav" ofType:nil] SoundKey:@"kaboom"];
[mSoundManager loadMusic:@"Musique - Finale.mp3" MusicKey:@"intro"];
[mSoundManager loadMusic:@"game_music01.wav" MusicKey:@"game01"];

[mSoundManager playMusic:@"intro" Loops:YES];

NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *volume = (NSString *)[userDefault objectForKey:@"volume"];
sunAnimate.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2);

if(volume == nil) {
    [userDefault setValue:@"1.0" forKey:@"volume"];
} else {
    float mVolume = [volume floatValue];
    [mSoundManager setMusicVolume:mVolume];
}

[self sunTurn];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.10 target:self selector:@selector(cligne) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

[image]

Can anyone see the problem with the above set of code?

This is my last error in the app code, so any help clearing this one would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Click on the blue symbol at the right side of the error line, a path through the code will be shown complete with comments.

Comment: BTW, and unrelated to your failure to release `SoundManager`, if this is not your root view controller, your code will also leak when you dismiss this view controller if you don't `invalidate` your repeating `NSTimer` in `viewDidDisappear` (or at some point ... but don't try to do it in `dealloc`). It might not be reported by Instruments, but if you watch your allocations, you'll see the view controller may not be released when you dismiss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not using ARC, if that is the case you are not releasing mSoundManager.

Either use ARC (Best choice) or `release` mSoundManager (Not so good choice).

Here is what you get by clicking on the right blue indicator:
[image]